# Can i avoid warning of Google Font - GDPR-compliant?

Tags: css, fonts, font-family

Im using this website [Link](https://www.e-recht24.de/google-fonts-scanner) to check if my website is Google Fonts GDPR-compliant it says:
[IMG](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VoV7D.png).
How can i solve this and not have this warning.

I tried to remove all my font-family locally, same result.
Im not using link to get fonts from google, im using it locally.

Comment: SOLVED it, the warning was coming from Google Maps and Google Captcha

Comment: how do you solve it?

Comment: @baycisk warning was not coming from font-family. I found that this warning could be from Google Captcha, Google Maps. From everything that comes from Google servers.